# FullCalendar's eventClick not working after changing view

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

Supposing that I want to open a modal popup when user clicks on a FullCalendar's event, I wrote some logic on the "eventClick" part of Full Calendar. This works fine until I'm on the default view, which I setted as "month".

If I try to switch from a view to another, though, this doesn't get fired, almost like it died.

What am I doing wrong? This is the code that I have for my Full Calendar. I've also tried to add a viewRender event as per the documentation but it's not working

```
function initCalendar2(oggetti){
    debugger;
    $('.calendar').fullCalendar({

      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        //right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,' +vistaAgenda
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listDay,listWeek'
      },
      views: {
        listDay: { buttonText: 'Lista Giorno'},
        listWeek: { buttonText: 'Lista Sett'}
      },


      eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                      debugger;
          //Send 2 values to the modal
          $("#dataArrivo").val(calEvent.start.toISOString().split('T')[0]);
          $("#dataConsegna").val(calEvent.end.toISOString().split('T')[0]);
          //Opens the modal
          var targeted_popup_class = $(this).attr('data-popup-open');
          $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);
          //e.preventDefault();
          var newDateOne;
          var newDateTwo;
          //This triggers only when the save button of the modal is clicked
          setTimeout(function() {
              $("#save").click(function() {
              var tmp1 = $("#dataArrivo").val();
              var tmp2 = $("#dataConsegna").val();
              newDateOne = new Date(tmp1);
              newDateOne.setDate(newDateOne.getDate());
              newDateTwo = new Date(tmp2);
              newDateTwo.setDate(newDateTwo.getDate());
              var tmp = calEvent.id.split("&");
              var idToSend = "";
              for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length-1; i++) {
                  if (i == tmp.length-2) {
                      idToSend += tmp[i];
                  } else {
                      idToSend += tmp[i]+"&";
                  }
              } if (newDateOne !== calEvent.start || newDateTwo !== calEvent.end) {
                  var actualDate = new Date(calEvent.start);
                  debugger;
                  //This ajax call will save the event's new dates in the DB
                  $.ajax({
                         url: 'calendariomanagement/listaPraticheFormJSONByIdProgettoCommittenteAndTipoVal/'+ idToSend +'/modDate/' +  nuovaDataArrivo.toDateString() + '&' +  nuovaDataConsegna.toDateString() + '&' + actualDate.toDateString(),
                         type:'POST',
                         async:false,
                         success: function(data) {
                             var targeted_popup_class = $(this).attr('data-popup-close');
                             $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
                             location.reload();
                             /*calEvent.start = dataUno;
                             calEvent.end = dataDue;
                             $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', calEvent);*/
                         }
                      });
              }
              }), 350}
          );

        },
      viewRender: function(view, element) {
          debugger;
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
      },
      locale: 'it',
      defaultView: 'month',
      defaultDate: moment(),
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      editable: false,
      eventDurationEditable: false,
      //weekends:false,
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events: oggetti
    });
```

Comment: `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');` in viewRender is unnecessary, fullCalendar will do this automatically. Meanwhile I have never heard of a case of eventClick not working just because the view changed. Are you sure that's actually the problem, or is it something in the code you placed _inside_ the eventClick which is causing a problem? You didn't show us that, so it's impossible to comment, but you should set breakpoints in your code to determine the exact point of failure. What version of fullCalendar is this? Do any console errors or warnings occur when you click the events?

Comment: Ok, I'm adding the whole logic! The version that I'm using is the latest

Comment: well, before you go to that effort, carry out the debugging I suggested - step through the code until a problem occurs, and check for console errors etc. You might find the problem more easily.

Comment: Of course I've already tried that way before posting and I couldn't find anything. eventclick logic added

Comment: So if you've done that debugging, then does that mean you're saying that the code in the `eventClick` is never executed at all after the view changes? None of it? It never enters that function when you click on an event?

Comment: P.S. Can we have the JSON of a couple of sample events for testing, please?

Comment: `$("#save").click(function() {`...is there somewhere in your code where you remove this event handler afterwards? Otherwise the more events you click on, the more handlers will be added to this button.

Comment: I have found the potential problem: after that I load FullCalendar for the first time, I do these two calls    $(".fc-content").attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
   $(".fc-content").attr('data-target','#myModal');                to add elements to all the events of Full Calendar. When I change view they, naturally, disappear

Comment: I see. Why don't you just use code inside the eventClick function to show the modal? I don't see any need to attach that attribute to anything. P.S. I had assumed that `$('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);` was the code for showing your modal popup, but perhaps that is for something else.

Comment: Yes you're right! Thank you for your help ADyson! I'm adding an answer with the solution of the problem, should it be handy for anybody in the future

Comment: No problem. You should also do something about the "Save" click handler I mentioned, otherwise if you click on a few different events it will keep running the "save" events for all the previous ones you clicked on as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting here for anybody that might fall in something similar my problem.
This was the modal popup that I was defining with HTML

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">

*<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Cambio data</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  <p> Inserire i nuovi valori nel formato anno-mese-giorno (es.: 2018-07-03). Nel 
caso non si volesse modificare nessun campo, semplicemente chiudere questo pop-up</p>
  <label for="arrivo">Data Arrivo:</label>
    <input type="text" name="dataArrivo" id="dataArrivo" class="form-control">
  <label for="consegna">Data Riconsegna:</label>
  <input type="text" name="dataConsegna" id="dataConsegna" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="save" data-dismiss="modal">Salva</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

*

After FullCalendar's load, I added this with jQuery

```
        $(".fc-content").attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
        $(".fc-content").attr('data-target','#myModal');
```

But of course, after changing the view, those attributes were lost and there was no chance to reinsert them. As a solution (pointed out by ADyson), the workaround was to define a modal with a bootbox object so that I could have it dynamically